# How to specify OpenShift image when creating a Job

Tags: openshift-enterprise

Under OpenShift 3.3, I'm attempting to create a Job using the `oc` command line tool (which apparently lacks argument-based support for Job creation), but I'm having trouble understanding how to make use of an existing app's image stream. For example, when my app does an S2I build, it pushes to the `app:latest` image stream. I want the Job I'm attempting to create to be run in the context of a new job-specific pod using my app's image stream. I've prepared a test Job using this YAML:

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: myapp-test-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 30
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myapp:latest
        command: ["echo", "hello world"]
```

When I create the above Job using `oc create -f job.yaml`, OpenShift fails to pull `myapp:latest`. If I change `image: myapp:latest` to `image: 172.30.194.141:5000/myapp/myapp:latest` (and in doing so, specify the host and port of my OpenShift instance's internal Docker registry), this works, but I'd rather not specify this as it seems like introducing a dependency on an OpenShift implementation detail. Is there a way to make OpenShift Jobs use images from an existing app without depending on such details?

The [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/dev_guide/jobs.html#creating-a-job) shows `image: perl`, but it's unclear on how to use a Docker image *built and stored within OpenShift*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned that you simply cannot yet use an ImageStream with a Job unless you specify the full address to the internal OpenShift Docker registry. Relevant GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/13042
- https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/13161
- https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/12672

Comment: This is now possible: https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/13161#issuecomment-642569395